# How to create dynamic menu using database and JSF

Tags: jsf

I want to create dynamic menu from Database
it's mean i have Catagory is main menu and some catagory such as Books, CDs, Managzine . . .
and Sub- Category is child of Category ( 2 table one is Category and table two is Sub-Category, and one - to many relationship) such as Ebooks for Books category, 007 for Cds, PC Worlds for MAgazine , Dictionary English for Books, Titanic for CDs

Dynamic menu load from database and display output to JSF page follow:

> Books
>
> ```
>  Ebooks
>  Dictionary
> ```
>
> CDs
>
> ```
>  007
>  Titanic
> ```
>
> Magazine
>
> ```
>  PC Worlds
>  IT Magazine
> ```

How can i do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to you to use [PrimeFaces Dynamic Menu](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu.jsf).

In order to install [PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org) read their [Getting Started](http://www.primefaces.org/gettingStarted.html) guide.

Comment: i know it but i don't like it's skin, and themroller CSS is complex, i was write my css and i want use my template :D thank you for your sugggest

Comment: you can always overwrite it:)